# GetAysnc by Id from many to many Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 tables `Center` (centerId, name, address,...) and `Student` (StudentId, NAme, Address) and I determined they have a many-to-many relationship. As a result, I have created a new table `CenterStudent` (centerId, studentId,...) to join these 2 tables, and I set both `centerId, studentId` is PK and FK, and cascade delete.

Now I want to get all records with the same studentId. So I wrote

```
var lists = await studentCenterService.GetAsync(cancellationToken, studentId);
```

But I get an error

> Entity type 'UserCenter' is defined with a 2-part composite key, but 1 values were passed to the 'DbSet.Find' method.

Could anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Show us some code how you design those 2 class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear - the `.Find()` method in EF works **only** on the **complete** PK - so if you have a PK made up from two columns (`centerId, studentId`), you cannot use `.Find()` to find all entries if you only supply `studentId`.

You need to use a

```
UserCenter.Where(x => x.studentId == studentId)
```

approach instead.

Comment: Thank all ,I found a solution for this issue,
1. I have created bool predicate
```Expression<Func<CenterStudent, bool>> predicate = CenterStudent=> CenterStudent.StudentId==studentId;
```


2. I userd this variable: 
```  var centers = await studentCenterService.GetAllAsync(predicate);
```

Comment: 3. Dotnet core support GetAllAsync function

```public virtual async Task<IList<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return await repository.GetAllAsync(predicate, cancellationToken);
        }
```
```